# ios開発にてprovisioning profileを作成するときにloading...から進まない

Tags: ios

以下のページにて Name と UDID を記載して continueを押してもloading...から先に進めません。
どういった原因が考えられますでしょうか？
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceCreate.action
[image: ios]

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
chrome や Firefoxだとうまくいかないようです。
safari で試したところうまくいきました。